# Python GEKKO MINLP optimization of energy system: How to build intermediates that are 2D arrays

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, gekko

I am currently implementing a MINLP optimization problem in Python GEKKO for determining the optimal operational strategy of a trigeneration energy system. As I consider the energy demand during all periods of different representative days as input data, basically all my decision variables, intermediates, etc. are 2D arrays.
I suspect that the declaration of the 2D intermediates is my problem. Right now I used list comprehension to declare 2D intermediates, but it seems like python cannot use these intermediates. Furthermore, the error *This steady-state IMODE only allows scalar values.* occurs.

Whenever I use the GEKKO m.Array function like this:
`e_GT = m.Array(m.Intermediate(E_GT[z][p]/E_max_GT) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P), (Z,P))`
it says, that the GEKKO object m.Intermediate cannot be called.

I would be very thankful if anyone could give me a hint.

Here is the complete code:

```
"""
Created on Fri Nov 22 10:18:33 2019

@author: julia
"""
# __Get GEKKO & numpy___
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# ___Initialize model___
m = GEKKO()

# ___Global options_____
m.options.SOLVER = 1                                                            # APOPT is MINLP Solver

# ______Constants_______                                                       
i = m.Const(value=0.05)                                                        
n = m.Const(value=10)                                                          
C_GT = m.Const(value=100000)                                                                         
C_RB = m.Const(value=10000)                                                            
C_HB = m.Const(value=10000)                                                            
C_RS = m.Const(value=10000)                                                           
C_RE = m.Const(value=10000)                                                          
Z = 12                                                                         
P = 24                                                                       
E_min_GT = m.Const(value=1000)                                                 
E_max_GT = m.Const(value=50000)                                                
F_max_GT = m.Const(value=100000)                                               
Q_max_GT = m.Const(value=100000)                                               
a = m.Const(value=1)                                                           
b = m.Const(value=1)                                                           
c = m.Const(value=1)                                                            
d = m.Const(value=1)                                                           
eta_RB = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                   
eta_HB = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                   
eta_RS = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                   
eta_RE = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                    
alpha = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                     

# ______Parameters______
T_z = m.Param([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31])                
C_p_Gas = m.Param(np.ones([P]))  
C_p_Elec = m.Param(np.ones([P]))
E_d = np.ones([Z,P])
H_d = np.ones([Z,P])
K_d = np.ones([Z,P])

# _______Variables______
E_purch = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                           
E_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
F_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
Q_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
Q_GT_RB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                          
Q_disp = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                           
Q_HB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
K_RS = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
K_RE = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
delta_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      
delta_RB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      
delta_HB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      
delta_RS = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                     
delta_RE = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      

# ____Intermediates_____      
R = m.Intermediate((i*(1+i)**n)/((1+i)**n-1))                                   
e_min_GT = m.Intermediate(E_min_GT/E_max_GT)                                    
e_GT = [m.Intermediate(E_GT[z][p]/E_max_GT) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]
f_GT = [m.Intermediate(F_GT[z][p]/F_max_GT) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]      
q_GT = [m.Intermediate(Q_GT[z][p]/Q_max_GT) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]                                  
Q_RB = [m.Intermediate(eta_RB*Q_GT_RB[z][p]*delta_RB[z][p]) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]   
F_HB = [m.Intermediate(eta_HB*Q_HB[z][p]*delta_HB[z][p]) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]       
Q_RS = [m.Intermediate(eta_RS*K_RS[z][p]*delta_RS[z][p]) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]       
E_RE = [m.Intermediate(eta_RE*K_RE[z][p]*delta_RE[z][p])  for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]      
F_Gas = [m.Intermediate(F_GT[z][p] + eta_HB*Q_HB[z][p]*delta_HB[z][p]) for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]                 
Cc = m.Intermediate(R*(C_GT + C_RB + C_HB + C_RS + C_RE))                                           
Cr_z = m.Intermediate((sum(C_p_Gas[p]*F_Gas[z][p] + C_p_Elec[p]*E_purch[z][p]) for p in range(P)) for z in range(Z)) 
Cr = m.Intermediate(sum(Cr_z[z]*T_z[z]) for z in range(Z))                                           

# ______Equations_______                                                
m.Equation(e_min_GT[z][p]*delta_GT[z][p] <= e_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))         
m.Equation(e_GT[z][p] <= 1*delta_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))                      
m.Equation(f_GT [z][p]== a*delta_GT[z][p] + b*e_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))       
m.Equation(q_GT [z][p]== c*delta_GT[z][p] + d*e_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))        
m.Equation(E_purch[z][p] + E_GT[z][p] == E_RE[z][p] + E_d[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)) 
m.Equation(Q_GT[z][p] == Q_disp[z][p] + Q_GT_RB[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))          
m.Equation(Q_RB[z][p] + Q_HB[z][p] == Q_RS[z][p] + H_d[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))    
m.Equation(K_RS[z][p] + K_RE[z][p] == K_d[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))                 
m.Equation(Q_disp[z][p] <= alpha*Q_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P))                     

# ______Objective_______
m.Obj(Cc + Cr)

#_____Solve Problem_____
m.solve()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extra square brackets are needed for 2D list definition. This gives a 2D list with 3 rows and 4 columns.

```py
[[p+10*z for p in range(3)] for z in range(4)]
# Result: [[0, 1, 2], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22], [30, 31, 32]]
```

If you leave out the inner brackets, it is a 1D list of length 12.

```py
[p+10*z for p in range(3) for z in range(4)]
# Result: [0, 10, 20, 30, 1, 11, 21, 31, 2, 12, 22, 32]
```

It also works when each element of the list is a Gekko `Intermediate`.

```py
[[m.Intermediate(p+10*z) for p in range(3)] for z in range(4)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, John, this has helped me a lot.

Comment: And thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11605538/baconbomber

Answer (score 1):

To diagnose the problem, I added a call to open the run folder before the solve command.

```py
#_____Solve Problem_____
m.open_folder()
m.solve()
```

I opened the `gk_model0.apm` model file with a text editor to look at a text version of the model. At the bottom it shows that there are problems with the last two intermediates and 9 equations.

```
    i2327=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    i2328=<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
End Intermediates
Equations
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0E51BC30>
    minimize (i2326+i2328)
End Equations

End Model
```

This happens when the `.value` property of a `Param` or `Var` is a lists or numpy array instead of a scalar value.

```py
# ______Parameters______
#T_z = m.Param([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]) 
T_z = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
```

There were also some other problems such as

- `e_min_GT` referenced as an element of a list instead of a scalar value in the first equation
- missing square brackets in the Intermediate list comprehensions to make the list 2D such as `[[2 for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]`
- dimension mismatch from `for z in range(Z)] for p in range(P)]` instead of `for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]`
- for better efficiency, use `m.sum` instead of `sum`

I made a few other changes as well. A differencing program should show them.

```py
"""
Created on Fri Nov 22 10:18:33 2019

@author: julia
"""
# __Get GEKKO & numpy___
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# ___Initialize model___
m = GEKKO()

# ___Global options_____
m.options.SOLVER = 1   # APOPT is MINLP Solver

# ______Constants_______                                                       
i = m.Const(value=0.05)                                                        
n = m.Const(value=10)                                                          
C_GT = m.Const(value=100000)                                                                         
C_RB = m.Const(value=10000)                                                            
C_HB = m.Const(value=10000)                                                            
C_RS = m.Const(value=10000)                                                           
C_RE = m.Const(value=10000)                                                          
Z = 12                                                                         
P = 24                                                                       
E_min_GT = m.Const(value=1000)                                                 
E_max_GT = m.Const(value=50000)                                                
F_max_GT = m.Const(value=100000)                                               
Q_max_GT = m.Const(value=100000)                                               
a = m.Const(value=1)                                                           
b = m.Const(value=1)                                                           
c = m.Const(value=1)                                                            
d = m.Const(value=1)                                                           
eta_RB = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                   
eta_HB = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                   
eta_RS = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                   
eta_RE = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                    
alpha = m.Const(value=0.01)                                                     

# ______Parameters______
T_z = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
C_p_Gas = np.ones(P)  
C_p_Elec = np.ones(P)
E_d = np.ones([Z,P])
H_d = np.ones([Z,P])
K_d = np.ones([Z,P])              

# _______Variables______
E_purch = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                           
E_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
F_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
Q_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
Q_GT_RB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                          
Q_disp = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                           
Q_HB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
K_RS = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
K_RE = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0)                                              
delta_GT = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      
delta_RB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      
delta_HB = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      
delta_RS = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                     
delta_RE = m.Array(m.Var, (Z,P), lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)                      

# ____Intermediates_____      
R = m.Intermediate((i*(1+i)**n)/((1+i)**n-1))                                   
e_min_GT = m.Intermediate(E_min_GT/E_max_GT)                                    
e_GT = [[m.Intermediate(E_GT[z][p]/E_max_GT) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]
f_GT = [[m.Intermediate(F_GT[z][p]/F_max_GT) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]      
q_GT = [[m.Intermediate(Q_GT[z][p]/Q_max_GT) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]                                  
Q_RB = [[m.Intermediate(eta_RB*Q_GT_RB[z][p]*delta_RB[z][p]) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]   
F_HB = [[m.Intermediate(eta_HB*Q_HB[z][p]*delta_HB[z][p]) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]       
Q_RS = [[m.Intermediate(eta_RS*K_RS[z][p]*delta_RS[z][p]) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]       
E_RE = [[m.Intermediate(eta_RE*K_RE[z][p]*delta_RE[z][p])  for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]      
F_Gas = [[m.Intermediate(F_GT[z][p] + eta_HB*Q_HB[z][p]*delta_HB[z][p]) for p in range(P)] for z in range(Z)]                 
Cc = m.Intermediate(R*(C_GT + C_RB + C_HB + C_RS + C_RE))                                           
Cr_z = [m.Intermediate(m.sum([C_p_Gas[p]*F_Gas[z][p] + C_p_Elec[p]*E_purch[z][p] for p in range(P)])) for z in range(Z)]
Cr = m.Intermediate(m.sum([Cr_z[z]*T_z[z] for z in range(Z)]))                                          

# ______Equations_______                                                
m.Equation([e_min_GT*delta_GT[z][p] <= e_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])         
m.Equation([e_GT[z][p] <= 1*delta_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])                      
m.Equation([f_GT [z][p]== a*delta_GT[z][p] + b*e_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])       
m.Equation([q_GT [z][p]== c*delta_GT[z][p] + d*e_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])        
m.Equation([E_purch[z][p] + E_GT[z][p] == E_RE[z][p] + E_d[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)]) 
m.Equation([Q_GT[z][p] == Q_disp[z][p] + Q_GT_RB[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])          
m.Equation([Q_RB[z][p] + Q_HB[z][p] == Q_RS[z][p] + H_d[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])    
m.Equation([K_RS[z][p] + K_RE[z][p] == K_d[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])                 
m.Equation([Q_disp[z][p] <= alpha*Q_GT[z][p] for z in range(Z) for p in range(P)])                     

# ______Objective_______
m.Obj(Cc + Cr)

#_____Solve Problem_____
#m.open_folder()
m.solve()
```

The problem solves with `1.6 sec` of solver time.

```
--------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :           13
   Constants    :           20
   Variables    :         5209
   Intermediates:         2320
   Connections  :          313
   Equations    :         5213
   Residuals    :         2893

 Number of state variables:           5209
 Number of total equations: -         2905
 Number of slack variables: -          864
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :           1440

 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      1.53 NLPi:    3 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    0 Obj:  2.69E+04 Gap:  0.00E+00
 Successful solution

 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    1.59730000000854      sec
 Objective      :    26890.6404951639     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```